# Can we evaluate z3py expressions from a string?

Tags: z3py

I could not find anything on the subject in the docs. I tried like : `s.add("Or(a==1, a==2, a==3), Or(b==1, b==2, b==3), Or(c==1, c==2, c==3)")`, but that is not working. Is it possible?

In sympy we can do this with `sympify` or `parse_expr`

**Edit:**

I see I can use just pythons `eval`. It also has `parse_smt2_string()`, but no reference how SMT2 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is the way to go. There's no support in z3py in any way to parse what's essentially a Python program. Note that for that to work, you should somehow have the variables `a`/`b` and `c` in the environment, either by explicit declaration or by `eval`'ing their declarations from a string like `"a, b, c = Ints('a b c')"`

Regarding your comment "No reference how SMT2 works:" SMTLib is the standard format accepted by all SMT-solvers, including z3. See here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/

Comment: eval has the problem,that I need to write a whole library to ensure the string seafty. So system users can no input harmful command lines etc

Comment: sure, that's no different than any use of `eval` in general. It should be avoided if at all possible.